# Connect PHP server socket to Android client Socket

Tags: java, php, android, sockets

I am trying to connect from PHP socket to client socket in order to send a message.

Here is the PHP server socket code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_implicit_flush();
 $address = '192.168.1.7';
// $address = 'www.xxxxxx.com';
$port = 15986;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
echo"socket created";
socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port);
socket_listen($sock);
$clients = array($sock);
while (true)
{

$read = $clients;
$write = null;
$except = null;


if (socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0) < 1)
    continue;

if (in_array($sock, $read))
{       
    $clients[] = $newsock = socket_accept($sock);
    socket_getpeername($newsock, $ip, $port);
    echo "New client connected: {$ip}\n";

    $key = array_search($sock, $read);
    unset($read[$key]);
}


foreach ($read as $read_sock)
{

    $data = @socket_read($read_sock, 4096, PHP_BINARY_READ);
    $data = trim($data);
    if ($data == "false")
    {
        $key = array_search($read_sock, $clients);
        unset($clients[$key]);
        echo "client disconnected.\n";
        continue;
    }      

    if (!empty($data))
    {
        echo " send {$data}\n";

        // do sth..


        socket_write($read_sock, $data);
      }
  } 
 }
socket_close($sock); // close the listening socket
?>
```

The java (Android) code used to send a message to the server:

```
 btnSendMessage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendMessage(sendMsg.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
private void sendMessage(String message) {
    try {
        if (null != socket) {
            if (!socket.isClosed()) {
                 outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter   outputStreamWriter = new 
    OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter),
                        true);

                out.println(message);
                if (message.equals("false"))
                {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener =
        new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask(
                        Constants.SOCKET_URL,
                        Constants.SOCKET_PORT);
                myClientTask.execute();
            }};

public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    String response = "";

    MyClientTask(String addr, int port){
        dstAddress = addr;
        dstPort = port;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {



        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
            isSocketConnected = true;
            Log.i(TAG, "Socket connected" );

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream =new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead;
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

/*
 * notice:
 * inputStream.read() will block if no data return
 */

            if (!socket.isClosed()) {
                if (isSocketConnected ) {
                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
                        byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        response = byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                        byteArrayOutputStream.reset();
                        Log.i(TAG,response);
                    }
                }

            }


            return  response;

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        }/*finally{
            if(socket != null){
                try {
                    isSocketConnected = false;
                    sendMessage("false");
                    Log.i(TAG,"Socket going to disconnect in finally");
                    socket.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }*/
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textResponse.setText(response);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    /*if(socket != null){
        try {
            isSocketConnected = false;
            sendMessage("false");
            outputStream.close();
            Log.i(TAG,"Socket going to disconnect in onPause");


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }*/
}
```

However, the following 400 error is received from the server. Note that this only occurs when connecting to the remote server, it all works when run locally:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Mon, 14 May 2018 13:55:43 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 347
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br /></p>
<p>Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: It is unclear who is calling your php script. And when. And from where.

Comment: Thanks for reply @greenapps i put php file into live server and i'm trying to conect socket through android app.

Comment: `am trying to connect from php socket to client socket.` That is impossible. A server socket cannot connect to a client. Only clients can connect to servers. The server has to wait and listen.

Comment: `i got HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request ` Where do you get that? Your server socket will not send such a message. What does your android client have to do with http protocol?

Comment: `Constants.SOCKET_URL,
                        Constants.SOCKET_PORT);
`. Please tell which values you use.

Comment: Ok,socket is connected but i got error from server when some text send to server.

Comment: @#$%! Post the relevant code. Dont mess around please.

Comment: Constanst.SOCKET_URL = www.myserverurl.com,Constants.PORT - 80

Comment: `Constants.PORT - 80` and `$port = 15986;` do not match. You should use Constants.PORT - 15986 too. You are connecting to the webserver instead of your php server socket.

Comment: i used 15986 port.now socket not connected

Comment: You should quote the exact exception message from the logcat of course.

Comment: i got timeout exception when i use 15986. instead of 80 port , I got 400 Bad request error...

Comment: Try with a browser on your device.

Comment: `$address = '192.168.1.7';` ?? Why? How does that match `www.myserverurl.com` ? Where does your server run exactly? A live server? Whats that? And your app?